# WordPress site login Redirect

Tags: login, wp-redirect

I try to log in to my WordPress website, It logs in but when I try to click anywhere in the dashboard, it redirects me to Login Page again.

What would be the reason, what steps I follow to keep login into my admin dashboard?
[image]

Comment: One option is to log in via FTP, move all of your plugins (/wp-content/plugins/) and your theme (/wp-content/themes/your-themes-name) to another folder so that WordPress will revert to a default theme and no plugins activated. Also make sure to clear your browser history/cache. Assuming that fixes the problem, you can then move your theme back and activate it, test the site, and move plugins back and activate them one by one, test the site, until you find out which theme or plugin is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks it worked :)